# There were no HTTP Requests logged for this event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, callback, sms, twilio

I am using the latest Twilio .NET SDK (5.0.2) in a VB.NET application. I am initiating a message via the REST Client that gets sent using a Messaging Service. In the Messaging Service I have "http://dev.leadtraxsolutions.com/Services/TwilioStatusUpdates.aspx" as the Status Callback URL.

Expected Results: Twilio to make a POST Request to the URL I have set up in the Messaging Service.

Actual Results: Message details in Twilio Console indicate "There were no HTTP Requests logged for this event"

Here is the code for sending the message:

```
    TwilioClient.Init(AccountSID, AuthToken)

    Dim NewToNumber As New PhoneNumber(ToNumber)
    Dim StatusCallback As New Uri("http://dev.leadtraxsolutions.com/Services/TwilioReplies.aspx")

    Try
        If Not MessageServiceSID Is Nothing Then
            If MessageServiceSID.Length > 0 Then
                _TwilioMessage = MessageResource.Create(NewToNumber, AccountSID, Nothing, MessageServiceSID, Body, Nothing)
            Else
                Dim NewFromNumber As New PhoneNumber(FromNumber)
                _TwilioMessage = MessageResource.Create(NewToNumber, AccountSID, NewFromNumber, Nothing, Body, Nothing, StatusCallback)
            End If
        End If
```

Can someone please help me understand why no HTTP request is being made?

Comment: This is probably best looked into by the [Twilio support team](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact). Please drop them a note and include some Message SIDs for messages you expected to get statusCallback events for but didn't.