# Twilio Forward SMS to email - Cannot find module 'got'

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I'm new to Twilio. I'm attempting to forward an SMS to an email address using this tutorial:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/07/forward-incoming-sms-messages-to-email-with-node-js-sendgrid-and-twilio-functions.html

I feel certain I've done everything it says to do, but I get an error 11200 HTTP retrieval failure every time, with these details:

> {
>       "message": "Cannot find module 'got'",
>       "name": "Error",
>       "stack": "Error: Cannot find module 'got'\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)\n    at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)\n    at Module.require
>   (module.js:596:17)\n    at Module.twilioRequire [as require]
>   (/var/task/node_modules/enigma-lambda/src/dependency.js:28:21)\n    at
>   require (internal/module.js:11:18)\n    at Object.
>   (/var/task/handlers/ZFa37cc3db9fd8db0501c2e5fc92137969.js:1:75)\n
>   at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)\n    at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)\n    at Module.load
>   (module.js:565:32)\n    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)" }

I've tried making absolutely sure I have the function written the same as the tutorial. I copied it directly from [the github page](https://github.com/philnash/useful-twilio-functions/tree/master/forward-message-as-email) to be sure. I'm not sure how to proceed in troubleshooting this, it seems it's telling me that 'got' isn't found but it's supposed to be available in Twilio functions. Any ideas? Thanks.

**Edit: Here is the code:**

```
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const requestBody = {
    personalizations: [{ to: [{ email: context.TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS }] }],
    from: { email: context.FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS },
    subject: `New SMS message from: ${event.From}`,
    content: [
      {
        type: 'text/plain',
        value: event.Body
      }
    ]
  };

  got
    .post('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${context.SENDGRID_API_KEY}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    })
    .then(response => {
      let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
      callback(null, twiml);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      callback(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: do you have `const got = require('got');` before `exports.handler = function(...` ??

Comment: @AlexBaban Yes thank you. I've edited my question to include the code I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the above code with `got` works with my Twilio and SendGrid accounts, I just tested, I don't know why you're having trouble..., maybe try to create a Twilio subaccount and run from there.

---

Second, if you still can't get `got` to work, here is some code, you could try, 
 and I'we also tested and it works. It's using `https` instead:

---

```
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {

    let postData = JSON.stringify({
        personalizations: [{
            to: [{
                email: 'somebody@gmail.com'
            }]
        }],
        from: {
            email: 'somebody@gmail.com'
        },
        subject: `New SMS message from: ${event.From}`,
        content: [{
            type: 'text/plain',
            value: event.Body
        }]
    });

    let postOptions = {
        host: 'api.sendgrid.com',
        port: '443',
        path: '/v3/mail/send',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer YOUR_API_KEY',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData),
        }
    };

    let req = https.request(postOptions, function (res) {
        // some code to handle the async response if needed
        let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
        callback(null, twiml);
    });

    req.write(postData);
    req.end();

};
```

---

Good luck!

Comment: I went over everything again today to make sure I didn't miss anything, but it's still the same error about 'got' not being found. But the code you posted worked flawlessly the first time! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using this approach, I am getting "There were no HTTP Requests logged for this event" and the SMS is not forwarded to email. I must be missing a simple setup step, but I don't know what I'm missing. I have my SendGrid API key (and it is configured as an environment variable and I access it using ${context.SENDGRID_API_KEY}.

Comment: @BugBuddy please see the comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930601/there-were-no-http-requests-logged-for-this-event

Answer (score 3):

After a little more research, I [found some comments on GitHub](https://github.com/philnash/useful-twilio-functions/commit/dc32b910ae4976e12e0cad02010b246aba7d4185) that indicate 'got' is no longer included by default in the Twilio dependencies. Per the instructions there I went to the [Runtime Functions Config section of the Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/functions/configure) and added got version 6.7.1 and now the original source code works!

I prefer Alex's solution however since it works "out of the box" and I'm keeping it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hello, I wrote the blog post that you linked at the start of your question and I am going to go update it right now. I have known about this for a little while, so I apologise for not getting to it.

Comment: Updated the blog post and the GitHub repo where you found the comments (that's also mine, sorry!).

Comment: @philnash The code at https://github.com/philnash/useful-twilio-functions/blob/master/forward-message-as-email/sendgrid.js is dated 05/07/2017 and still doesn't work. This is my first attempt to use Twilio and I'm unimpressed with the documentation.

Comment: Hi @cja, What doesn't work abou that code for you? Did you add `got` as a dependency in your [Functions configuration page](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/functions/configure) as described in [the README](https://github.com/philnash/useful-twilio-functions/tree/master/forward-message-as-email#dependencies)?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by making sure that "got" is installed as a dependency under these settings here:
https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/functions/configure

[Functions Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Fkz.png)